# Why does my Laptop moniter go blank?

Tags: windows-vista, laptop, graphics-card

Every once in a while my laptop's monitor goes black. It does it mostly when doing graphics heavy stuff. I'm thinking that the graphics card is over heating but I don't know what to do about it. Any Ideas?

**UPDATE: I know It's not the monitor, Also I don't think my graphics card has a thermometer. It does seem to be running when it goes black**

Comment: good question.  This occasionally happens to me on my HP laptop.  I usually have to force a powerdown to get the LCD to start working again.  Annoying.

Comment: I know It's not the monitor, Also I don't think my graphics card has a thermometer. It does seem to be running when it goes black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also run a stress test on the video card 
Link for stress test - http://www.ozone3d.net/smf/index.php?topic=1440.0

And see what happens to the external monitor and the lcd display.

Also look keep an eye on the internal temperature with a program like speedfan to see maybe its a heat issue where the video chip is= shutting down to protect it self.

Link for speedfan - http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php

Answer (score 1):

Try connecting an external monitor. If the problem is with the graphics card the external monitor will also be effected. If the external monitor is OK, then the problem with with the screen hardware, or possible a bad connection.

Answer (score 1):

Does the computer appear to keep running when the screen is blank? Or is the notebook shutting down? If it appears to be shutting down see [my question here](https://superuser.com/questions/2125/lg-r500-notebook-crashing) for some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to do about laptop temperature in general is to check whether the fans are working properly, clean them, and check whether the thermal paste has worn out. Even if it's only the GPU temperature going up, I believe that a lower temperature in the rest of the laptop will improve things in any case.