# How do I understand or interpret the information in an ACPI .asl file?

Tags: acpi, asl, dsdt

Dumping the contents of the Windows Registry, located at 
**HKLM\HARDWARE\ACPI\DSDT** , I can get the DSDT, which I believe is the **Differentiated System Description Table**.  More information about what a DSDT is, [here](http://acpi.sourceforge.net/dsdt/index.php).

Using Microsoft's [ASL Compiler](http://www.acpi.info/toolkit.htm), I can transform this binary file into an .asl format. (.asl = ACPI Source Language, which is a text format, readable in notepad.

How do I interpret this thing? Specifically I'd like to know what settings or statements in that file, if any, control the fan-speed-to-cpu-temperature gates. Then I want to modify those settings and reload the DSDT into the registry using, again, the ASL Compiler. I know how to reload it.  I just don't know what parts to modify.

Thanks for any hints you can provide.

---

**EDIT**
See also, [this blog post](http://notebookequus.blogspot.com/) for an overview of what I am trying to do. Actually I have done this successfully in the past, see [Why is my Compaq nc8430 so darned HOT?](https://superuser.com/questions/29032/why-is-my-compaq-nc8430-laptop-so-darned-hot) .
Now I would like to do something similar, but for an HP G60-244DX.

Comment: not sure why someone feels the need to remove the links I inserted into the question. They're there for a reason.  If you don't want to click on them, don't.

Comment: If you read my comment for the edit, I asked if you seriously wanted everyone to download the actual compiler?

Comment: yes I understand.  And you removed all 3 links.  If you honestly wanted to help, you could have modified the link so that it pointed to information about the ASL Compiler, rather than the MSI download; instead you just destroyed information.

Comment: We happened to edit at the same time, which is why I overwrote your stuff. Come on. I have a job to do, I didn't know where to link to, and really don't have the time to search for those links. The only reason I noticed is because I was interested in the topic, and when I clicked on the link on my Mac it tried to download a file, and I edited it out. I assumed you would come back and fix it based on the notes I made during the edit. When **I** edited it there was only 1 link and I submitted after you.

Comment: Fair enough, but I respectfully suggest that if you don't have time to search for more appropriate links, then add a comment asking for a change, but above all don't edit carelessly and destroy content.